# Extracting full article text via the newsanchor package [in R]

Tags: r, feed

I am using the newsanchor package in R to try to extract entire article content via NewsAPI. For now I have done the following :

```
require(newsanchor)
results <- get_everything(query = "Trump +Trade", language = "en")
test <- results$results_df
```

This give me a dataframe full of info of (maximum) a 100 articles. These however do not containt the entire actual article text. Rather they containt something like the following:

```
[1] "Tensions between China and the U.S. ratcheted up several notches over the weekend as Washington sent a warship into the disputed waters of the South China Sea. Meanwhile, Google dealt Huaweis smartphone business a crippling blow and an escalating trade war co… [+5173 chars]"
```

Is there a way to extract the remaining 5173 chars. I have tried to read the documentation but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at least with free plan. If you go through the documentation at https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything in the Response object section it says :

> content - string
>
> The unformatted content of the article, where available. This is truncated to 260 chars for Developer plan users.

So all the `content` is restricted to only 260 characters. However, `test$url` has the link of the source article which you can use to scrape the entire content but since it is being aggregated from various sources I don't think there is one automated way to do this.

Comment: I have looked further into this and you are entirely correct. Thanks so much for answering. Now trying to build a generic website scraper